# Auto scroll while clicking UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath ios-ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5, xcode5

How to scroll up the TableView **or** cell while i am clicking loadmore from option from UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[arrData count]-1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

arrData is the Data source you feed to the TableView. By setting IndexPath to [arrData count] you can go to the bottom of the TableView